# SharePoint 2010 Navigation site

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Instead of the default

Im using

```
             <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="MenuRepeater" DataSourceID="topSiteMap">
                <HeaderTemplate>
               <div class="arrowlistmenu">
              </HeaderTemplate>
            <SeparatorTemplate>
             <img src="images/eOne_leftmenu_divider.gif" height="2" width="164" />
              </SeparatorTemplate>

                        <ItemTemplate>

                         <h3 class="menuheader expandable">

                         <a href="<%# Eval("Url")%>"><%# Eval("Title")%></a></h3>

                     <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="ChildMenuRepeater"                                                                                                                       

                     DataSource='<%# ((SiteMapNode)Container.DataItem).ChildNodes %>'>
                          <HeaderTemplate><ul class="categoryitems"></HeaderTemplate>
                          <ItemTemplate>
                          <li><a href="<%# Eval("Url")%>"><%# Eval("Title")%></a></li>
                          </ItemTemplate>
                          <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
                      </asp:Repeater>
                       </ItemTemplate>

                       <FooterTemplate></div></FooterTemplate>
                   </asp:Repeater>
```

but it is giving me an error.

Comment: @ChrisBint: Isn't it funny when people say "I get an error" and don't include the error itself?

Comment: should i add somethinf in the web.config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post describes how to style the top navigation bar in SharePoint using repeaters. http://samirfarid.wordpress.com/2012/01/03/style-sharepoint-top-navigation-using-repeaters/